# Position the <li> dot at the top

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm trying to get the bulletpoint in a list to align at the top of the instead of the bottom.

Here is an example of what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/2ma994cr/

```
<ul class="a">
    <li>Thing 1</li>
    <li><iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3B49N46I39Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
    <li>Thing 3</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see in the fiddle, the bulletpoint for the embedded object is at the bottom.

Is there an `<li>` style I can add in CSS that will align it to the top or another way around this?

Comment: Sorry for the weird punctuation. It wouldn't let me post the Q until I added code. I guess it messed with the layout.

Comment: I think I cleaned it up enough to get your point across.

Comment: Thanks @Cᴏʀʏ not sure where I went wrong

Comment: It was just the indentation of the code for your `<ul>`. You didn't have the `<li>` elements or the `</ul>` end tag indented far enough (at least four spaces).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should vertically align the content within the `<li>`, not the bullet itself. Try this:

```
li > * {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Note: You may need to adjust the selector; what I have only applies the rule to the immediate children of each `<li>`. Make it more or less specific according to your needs.

An [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ma994cr/1/).

Comment: Thanks! `vertical-align: top;` is more suitable to my case.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the item inside is display: flex

Comment: It seems that children of li must not be `display:block`. try `display:inline`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```css
li {
  display: block;
}
li:before{
  content: "•";
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="a">
    <li>Thing 1</li>
    <li><iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3B49N46I39Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
    <li>Thing 3</li>
</ul>
```