# Bullet points misaligned on Firefox when list item contains a button

Tags: html, css

On Firefox but not Chrome, I find that when a button is a direct descendent of a list item, and its inner text wraps to multiple lines, the bullet point lines up with the last line of the text, when I expect it to line up with the first line. This looks weird.

I can fix the bullet point alignment in various hacky ways, but I'm trying to understand whether this is a Firefox bug, a Chrome bug, a gap somewhere in the spec, or if I am misunderstanding something about which styles are having this effect.

The issue seems limited to button elements. I get consistent display when using spans. Here's an example:

```html
<ul style="width: 300px;">
  <li>The following list item looks OK in Chrome, misaligned in FF:</li>
  <li><button>This is just dummy text to demonstrate the issue, which only happens when an element wraps to a second line.</button></li>
  <li><span>An inline span works fine when the text wraps as you can see with this element, so I think display:inline should work on the button. But you can see an inline button is still misaligned in Firefox:</span></li>
  <li><button style="display:inline;">This is just dummy text to demonstrate the issue, which only happens when an element wraps to a second line.</button></li>
  <li><span style="display:inline-block;">An inline-block span has a misaligned bullet in all browsers, when the text wraps to multiple lines.</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: span and buttons are never (and can never) be the same even if you apply the same style to them. Buttons are special elements that may not behave the same cross browser

Answer (score 0):

In your (quite particular) case, just apply `vertical-align: top;` to all direct children of `li` elements, otherwise all inline elements will (by default) be aligned at their baseline:

```css
li > * {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul style="width: 300px;">
  <li>The following list item looks OK in Chrome, misaligned in FF:</li>
  <li><button>This is just dummy text to demonstrate the issue, which only happens when an element wraps to a second line.</button></li>
  <li><span>An inline span works fine when the text wraps as you can see with this element, so I think display:inline should work on the button. But you can see an inline button is still misaligned in Firefox:</span></li>
  <li><button style="display:inline;">This is just dummy text to demonstrate the issue, which only happens when an element wraps to a second line.</button></li>
  <li><span style="display:inline-block;">An inline-block span has a misaligned bullet in all browsers, when the text wraps to multiple lines.</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This appears to be the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681147/position-the-li-dot-at-the-top.  Perhaps this is better marked as a dupe?

Comment: I know that I can fix the alignment on the inline button by giving it vertical align: top, but the span is vertical-align baseline and looks fine. Why should the button and span be different, when both are given the same display property?